# Java DecimalFormat formatting zero

Tags: java, zero, decimalformat

I am trying to format my (usually large) numeric output with space as thousands separator using the following code:

```
final String PATTERN = "#,##0";
int value1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int value2 = 0;
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(PATTERN, dfs);
System.out.println("`" + df.format(value1) + "`");
System.out.println("`" + df.format(value2) + "`");
```

However, which leaves me very confused, the output is:

```
`2 147 483 647`
``
```

Please, what is the proper pattern to achieve my desired result:

```
`2 147 483 647`
`0`
```

Comment: I get `0` when I run your code. What Java version and Locale are you using?

Comment: I get `0` too... JDK 1.7

Comment: Could you print your default `Locale` ?

Comment: Works for me too (1.7.0_21-b12)

Comment: I am using JDK 1.7.0_21 with Source/Binary format set to 1.6 in the project. Default locale seems to be en_US.

And finally, I also get `0` in the result. Some old version must have been stuck on the server with redeploy not overwriting it and it has finally just got removed. Do I delete the whole question/thread?

Comment: @PeterLényi, you can always create an answer and accept it.  Deleting the thread isn't helpful for those who may run into the same issue later, which is the principle that StackOverflow, and its related sites, are built on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the good people have already responded in the comments, the pattern is correct and produces the desired result.

The problematic part has been just one step away. Assuming code in the question, then if `df.format(getNumber());` fails in `#getValue()`, the `#format()` is never executed, which (in my code) eventually resulted in empty string in the user interface and my confusion.